# Show video in dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-videoview

I want to display video in dialog box
before the video was play in activity and it worked correctly,
but when I try to show video in dialog everything is broken.
It looks like video view becomes transparent, but clicks on video handled correctly.
Whether is a solution of this problem?

Comment: Using `Dialog` or `AlertDialog`??

Comment: Custom dialog wich extend android.app.Dialog class

Comment: Try using DialogFragment.

Comment: I can't use DialogFragment, because this is sided module which will be integrate in different android projects, but FragmentDialog works only with FragmentActivity for android < 3.0.
And for example activity in unity application extends NativeActivity. I can't change it to FragmentActivity